# How can I create or load new language in spacy NLP?

Tags: python, nlp, jupyter-notebook, spacy

How can I create or load new language in spacy NLP ? for example spacy.load('tr') in python. editor jupyter.
How can I create new entity but different entity ? for example FOOTBALL_CLUB.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do spacy.load('tr') right now.You can see below link what are the languages are supported by spaCy.
[SpaCy supported languages](https://spacy.io/usage/models)

For language turkish, spaCy has started work on it.You can help to improve the language data.You can clone it from github and load your preferred language.

[Github/spaCy](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy)

You can also train your own corpus containing new entities.
[Training examples](https://spacy.io/usage/training)
Thank you